# Android audio/video Streaming is not working for Wowza server

Tags: android, video, wowza

I want to implement video streaming using the Wowza server. So, is there any tutorial that how Wowza works for Android devices?

Videos are stored at server side. So, to fetch video using URL and play it on Android. I tried some examples, but I got error, "Sorry, this video can not be played". I am using URL `enter code here`definst/mp4:amazons3/XXX/XXX_42u9Ug_MP4Akon-Beautifulft.ColbyO%27Donis%2CKardinalOffishall(1).mp4/manifest.f4m">http://XXXX.amazonaws.com/vods3/*definst*/mp4:amazons3/XXX/XXX_42u9Ug_MP4Akon-Beautifulft.ColbyO%27Donis%2CKardinalOffishall(1).mp4/manifest.f4m.

Below is the source code.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);

    mPath = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.path);
    mPath.setText("http://XXXX.amazonaws.com/vods3/_definst_/mp4:amazons3/XXX/XXXX_42u9Ug_MP4Akon-Beautifulft.ColbyO%27Donis%2CKardinalOffishall(1).mp4/manifest.f4m");

    mPlay = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play);
    mPause = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.pause);
    mReset = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reset);
    mStop = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.stop);

    mPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            playVideo();
        }
    });
    mPause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.pause();
            }
        }
    });
    mReset.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.seekTo(0);
            }
        }
    });
    mStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            if (mVideoView != null) {
                current = null;
                mVideoView.stopPlayback();
            }
        }
    });
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            playVideo();

        }

    });
}

private void playVideo() {
    try {
        final String path = mPath.getText().toString();
        Log.v(TAG, "path: " + path);
        if (path == null || path.length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(VideoStreamingDemo.this,
                    "File URL/path is empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            // If the path has not changed, just start the media player
            if (path.equals(current) && mVideoView != null) {
                mVideoView.start();
                mVideoView.requestFocus();
                return;
            }
            current = path;
            mVideoView.setVideoPath(getDataSource(path));
            mVideoView.start();
            mVideoView.requestFocus();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "error: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        if (mVideoView != null) {
            mVideoView.stopPlayback();
        }
    }
}

private String getDataSource(String path) throws IOException {
    if (!URLUtil.isNetworkUrl(path)) {
        return path;
    } else {
        URL url = new URL(path);
        URLConnection cn = url.openConnection();
        cn.connect();
        InputStream stream = cn.getInputStream();
        if (stream == null)
            throw new RuntimeException("stream is null");
        File temp = File.createTempFile("mediaplayertmp", "dat");
        temp.deleteOnExit();
        String tempPath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(temp);
        byte buf[] = new byte[128];
        do {
            int numread = stream.read(buf);
            if (numread <= 0)
                break;
            out.write(buf, 0, numread);
        } while (true);
        try {
            stream.close();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e(TAG, "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
        return tempPath;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To play videos on Android devices use "RTSP" and the url format is

```
rtsp://wowzaserveripaddress:1935/applicationname/mp4:directoryname/videofilename.mp4
```

or

```
rtsp://wowzaserveripaddress:1935/applicationname/mp4:videofilename.mp4
```

For Example

```
rtsp://192.168.1.11:1935/vod/mp4:sample.mp4
```

Ensure that your wowza server is running before your testing

Try this in your native android player or MXPlayer

Answer (score 0):

RTSP is a real headache
try
[http://server_ip:1935/vod/definst/'foldername'/mp4:'videoname'.mp4/playlist.m3u8]
ex: my video name 'camness.mp4' inside folder 'trend'. then my url is
[http://server_ip:1935/vod/definst/trend/mp4:camness.mp4/playlist.m3u8]